# Need assistance to compile X264 in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, x264, libx264

I have been trying to open x264 code base in Visual Studio, by creating a separate project for it, but without any success.

I thought it should have been straight forward. I could build X264 code using MinGW, but I need to edit the code and extract motion estimation code.

Has anyone compiled/run the x264 from Visual Studio?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time this answer was written, there were no support for building x264 with Visual Studio.
Instead you should build it with MinGW/gcc or Intel Compiler. For instance, there are some howtos around - take a [look here](http://www.ayobamiadewole.com/Blog/How-to-build-x264-or-libx264.dll-in-Windows) and [here](http://kemuri9.net/dev/x264/other/intel_howto.html).

For me, the second method has worked out.

Comment: I will only add the reason why it so. That is because x264 is written in C99 standard (dialect of C) and MSVC compiler doesn't fully support it (there was some progress in the latest version [2013] of MSVS but afaik support is still not full and so it fails to build x264). This can be workaround by using Intel C Compiler but most don't have it. As option you can try to look at x264's fork: [Direct264](http://sourceforge.net/p/direct264/code/HEAD/tree/x264/). It have MSVS project files and can be build with it.

Comment: that doom10.org forum is closed to guest and new registrations seem not to be allowed. very frustrating!

Comment: Forum is dead. This answer is no longer suitable.

Answer (score 1):

Someone has done the job. They maintain a fork with a proper visual studio project

http://siliconandlithium.blogspot.ca/2014/03/building-x264-on-windows-with-visual.html